# Почему код возвращает None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Мне нужно чтобы код возвращал значение переменной *value*, но в итоге возвращает *None*. Почему?

```
def count(arr, value=0):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return value
    value += 1
    del arr[0]
    count(arr, value)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(count(a))
```

Comment: Потому что функция ничего не возвращает, если условие в первом if не выполняется (нет return для этого случая)

Comment: для данной функции достаточно одного параметра - `arr`:   `def count(arr): if len(arr) == 0: return 0; return 1 + count(arr[1:])`

Answer (score 2):

надо протащить последний ретурн до первого вызова

```
def count(arr, value=0):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return value
    value += 1
    del arr[0]
    return count(arr, value)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(count(a))
```